# What is the meaning of this expression?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis

Does "next player's turn" mean "next turn of the player" or "turn of the next player"? Or can it mean either depending on the context? In this particular case the context is a two player board game such as chess (but not chess) where players alternate to take their turns.

Meta: also I'd appreciate some help with the good question title, as mine clearly is not good.

Comment: You have surely answered your own question, simply by the way you ask whether it's ***next turn** [of the player]* or *[turn of the] **next player***. You'd hardly do that unless you meant (and expected us to understand) that the word ***next*** normally modifies *the next noun [phrase]* (the one that immediately follows).

Comment: @FumbleFingers while "player" is a noun "player's" is a possessive form, and as such it looks and behaves more like an adjective than a noun. That's why I got confused. I'm not a native speaker of the language (obviously) so it did not occur to me even for a second that I had answered my own question. In fact I'm still not sure why you are thinking this.

Comment: To expand on @FumbleFinger's comment, if you write **"the green parrot's fruit",** you mean the fruit belonging to the green parrot. If you write **"the parrot's green fruit",** it's the green fruit belonging to the parrot. Similarly, **"the next player's turn"** is the turn of the next player, and not the same as **"the player's next turn"**, which is the next turn of the player.

Comment: *Next* could modify a noun phrase ahead of it. However, *player's turn* is not a NP. It cannot reach across *player's* to modify *turn*. Compare other cases where *next* occurs before an unambiguous noun phrase and the difference will be clear.

Comment: @Peter: I'm not sure that's strictly true. Can we not contrive a context where the man behind the counter in a pet store says *"We stock several different fruits suitable for this parrot, sir. Would you like the green parrot's fruit, or the red one?"* (Or even, if it was a [*Pythonesque*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218) shop, *"...the green **dead** parrot's fruit"*.)

Comment: @Kris: good point ... for example, a *"green carpenter's square"* is not a square belonging to a green carpenter, but a green tool called a *"carpenter's square"*.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it is the other player's turn... because you have finished your turn.

e.g. In chess, you move your Rook (a chess piece). So, your turn is over. It is now the next player's turn, so  you must wait for him (her) to finish.

Comment: Can you include why you think so? Else it's only an opinion.

Comment: "only an opinion"... Go around and talk to real people mate... and play chess. And then you will know what "next player's turn" means (and that I am right) :)

Answer (score 0):

In light of comments to the question, I think we have to accept that *syntactically*, constructions of the form *the [adjective] [possessive] [noun]* are inherently ambiguous. Consider, for example,...

> [*a big girl's blouse*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22big%20girls%20blouse%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22a%20big%20girl%27s%20blouse%22&tbm=bks)

Putting aside the fact that this is [informal British term](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blouse) for *a weak, cowardly, or oversensitive man*, there's structural ambiguity as to whether the "literal" meaning is a *blouse belonging to a **big girl***, or a ***big blouse*** belonging to a girl.

With OP's example, we could in principle contrive a context where a game involved turns taken by both *players* and the *game controller* - a betting game, for example, distinguishing between (any) *player's turn* and the *banker's turn*. Feasibly therefore, one might say *"We'll take a break after the next **player's turn**"* (but there might be a ***banker's turn*** before that).

To make the context even more contrived, if we suppose there's only *one* player in the game (along with the banker), he could be identified as ***the*** player. It would be meaningless to speak of the ***next*** player, since there's only one, but we could validly refer to *the next turn of the player*.

---

TL;DR: By default, *next* modifies the first "credible" [NP](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/nounphraseterm.htm) ***after*** it. It would be semantically perverse to interpret *player's turn* as the likely referent, given that *player* is perfectly credible. The possessive apostrophe modifies the nearest credible NP ***before*** it (in OP's case, that's *next player*).